# Outlook Signature folder in Windows OS

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have been working on an application which integrate with VSTO components in order to leverage MS Office including Outlook. In this, I have a method which read the all defined outlook signature and import it into our application. All works well and I am accessing the signature location using the following logic.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),@"Microsoft\Signatures");
```

The above code works fine with English version of Windows (en-us,en-gb etc).

Does someone have exposure towards Microsoft OS installed using German language or any other? If so, how do I generalize or customize logic which does the aforementioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "special folder" api for outlook folders.  Your only choice is to translate it to each language you want to support.

Comment: You are suggesting to switch between hardcoded sig path based on language. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @s_nair - There isn't any other choice.  There is no way to get this path from the API, thus you have to use localized paths.  One option might be to access the Outlook API and try to find the folder that way, but that typically requires that outlook be running (or that it load it) to work.